# Enable mouse scroll in flipview children

Tags: winjs

In my WinJS application, I use a flipview, with a Listview inside it.

The listview as a long content, so it is scrollable : the scrollbar is visible, I can scroll with the finger on a touch screen, but the mouse wheel doesn't work.

After looking at the flipview source code, I added the *win-interactive* class on my listview, and now I can use the mouse wheel to scroll, but the problem is that the scroll also applies to the flipview container : the mouse scroll directly between the different flipview items.

Is there a way to enable the scroll on the listview, without modifying the flipview behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, you can subscribe to the `mousewheel` event being fired in your `ListView` and `stopPropagation()` from there to the `FlipView`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work : the stopPropagation() does'nt stop anything. (and the preventDefault() completely stops the scroll in the listview)